# Fancybox reload after content changes

Tags: fancybox, visualization

The problem is that I can't figure out how to resize the fancybox after the content is fully loaded.

Maybe there is a way to add some kind of changelistener to the content div inside the fancybox where you can call some kind of fancybox.resize function.

I've tried some things and had some problems with this before with autocomplete inside a fancybox.

I then used the .live function and binded an event.

This is the code inside the fancybox:

```
<div id="fancy_chart_div"></div>
```

So after a chart has been loaded into this div then the fancybox should resize depending on the content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can manually call a fancybox resize using the API:

```
$.fancybox.update()
```

Call this after your chart is loaded.

Comment: I found a link allready where this issue has been discussed:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178750/resize-fancybox-with-dynamic-content?rq=1)